# Unable to run UDF on hive server

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, hive

I'm running hive in thrift server mode. I have a UDF in a jar file that I'm trying to use by running

```
add jar <path to jar>
create temporary function func_name as 'com.test.udf.UDF_CLASS'
```

However, when I run the create temporary function command I get an error

> Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error,
>   return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask

I've checked that the name & path of the jar and that the user running the hive server has all the correct permissions to access the jar. What is weird is if I run hive in CLI mode and run the exact same commands, then everything works. Any ideas on why hive CLI may be behaving differently from the hive thrift server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the problem using the following steps:

1) Place each UDF jar in /usr/lib/hive/auxlib

2) Specify the path to each jar in hive-site.xml for the hive.aux.jars.path property (ex: file:///usr/lib/hive/auxlib/jar1.jar,file:///usr/lib/hive/auxlib/jar2.jar)

3) Create a script to make a thrift request to the hive server to run create temporary function func_name as 'com.test.udf.ClassName' for each UDF after the hive server is started

Edit: For Hive 0.9 no matter what I did, Hiveserver couldn't find jars in the auxlib directory. To get this to work on Hiveserver 0.9 I had to just dump the jar in the directory specified by Hive's classpath.

Answer (score 10):

After playing with this for awhile I got it to work by putting the .class file into a directory structure that matches it's package, and adding it to the .jar from there. For reference I've included the whole process, including compiling and inserting into hive.

1. I used the UDF example [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins)
2. Compile it: `javac -classpath $CLASSPATH Lower.java`. *Note: the CLASSPATH was defined like this: `CLASSPATH=$(ls $HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-serde-*.jar):$(ls $HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-exec-*.jar):$(ls $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-core-*.jar)`, as described [here](http://findingscience.com/hadoop/hive/2011/01/07/compiling-user-defined-functions-for-hive-on-hadoop.html).*
3. **Copy the .class file to a folder com/example/hive/udf/**
4. **Added it to a jar with this command: `jar -cf lower.jar com/example/hive/udf/Lower.class`**
5. Verify that the package looks right: `jar -tf lower.jar`. You should see a line like this: `com/example/hive/udf/Lower.class`.
6. Import the jar into hive. `add jar lower.jar; create temporary function my_lower as 'com.example.hive.udf.Lower';`

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted this.. I had the same problem and this worked for me...

Using hive 0.11.0 on AWS EMR

Comment: Works for me too :) The link in the first step is broken now, I think it should be pointing to: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins

Answer (score 0):

You can also do by passing the --auxpath option to the hive command
hive --auxpath /path-to-/hive-examples.jar

or

by setting the HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH environmental varialble.

Comment: Neither of those work with the Thrift Hive Server for version 0.7.0 (the version I'm using) since 0.7.0 only accepted HIVE_PORT as a command line option rather than the standard HIVE_OPTS. The Hive CLI has supported the two ways you mentioned for a while, but support for those when running in hiveserver mode was only added in 0.8 I think.